# Fazer else em jquery para controlar scrolltop

Tags: jquery, css

Tenho uma div `.menuFixo`, que quando ela atingir **31px** de scroll ela fique com `top: 0`, caso contrário, fique `top:31px`, fiz com Jquery, mas não funcionou.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 31) {
        $(".menuFixo").css("top", "0");
    };
    else if ($(window).scrollTop() < 31) {
        $(".menuFixo").css("top", "31px");
    };

});
```

Comment: Acho que não precisa do segundo `if`, apenas `else`

Comment: tentei só com `else` e não funcionou

Comment: @Felipe Stoker Tente colocar um `Alert` para ver se esta chamando a função.

Comment: Não consegui descobrir o que era, por fim eu fiz o que eu queria de outra forma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olhe se pode te ajudar.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
          $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 31) {
                $(".menuFixo").css("top", "0");
          }else {
                $(".menuFixo").css("top", "31px");
          }
                });
        });
```

Comment: Descobri meu erro, eu estava encerrando com `;` antes de iniciar o `else`.