# Problema com jQuery scrollTop() no chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fala pessoal.

Estou com o seguinte problema, tenho um código que identifica quando ocorreu um scroll da página para poder subir o meu menu lateral ao ser realizado um scroll. Funciona no IE e no FireFox porém não funciona no Chrome.

Segue o exemplo de código.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var $body = $('body');
        var $pagiSidebar = $('.page-sidebar');

        $body.scroll(function (event) {

            console.log('scrolled $(body).scrollTop() = ' + $('body').scrollTop());

            console.log('scrolled $(document).scrollTop() = ' + $(document).scrollTop());

            console.log('scrolled $(window).scrollTop() = ' + $(window).scrollTop());

            console.log('scrolled $(html).scrollTop() = ' + $('html').scrollTop());

            console.log('scrolled $(html, body).scrollTop() = ' + $('html, body').scrollTop());

            console.log('scrolled $(html, body, document).scrollTop() = ' + $('html, body, document').scrollTop());

            if ($body.scrollTop() > 47) {
                $pagiSidebar.addClass('top-zero');
            }
            else {
                $pagiSidebar.removeClass('top-zero');
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

Com isso obtive os seguintes resultados.

```
Firefox e IE = 

scrolled $(body).scrollTop() = 270 
scrolled $(document).scrollTop() = 0 
scrolled $(window).scrollTop() = 0
scrolled $('html').scrollTop() = 0 
scrolled $('html, body').scrollTop() = 0 
scrolled $('html, body', document).scrollTop() = 0


Chrome = 

scrolled $(body).scrollTop() = 0
scrolled $(document).scrollTop() = 0 
scrolled $(window).scrollTop() = 0
scrolled $('html').scrollTop() = 0 
scrolled $('html, body').scrollTop() = 0 
scrolled $('html, body', document).scrollTop() = 0
```

Alguém sabe o porque disso ou se existe outra maneira de conseguir esse mesmo resultado sem usar o scrollTop ?

**Solução**

Galera, após explorar um pouco mais e analisar as sugestões cheguei na seguinte solução.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var $body = $('body');
        var $pageSidebar = $('.page-sidebar');
        var $pageContainer = $('.page-container');

        $body.scroll(function (event) {

            if ($pageContainer.offset().top > 0) {
                $pageSidebar.css("top", $pageContainer.offset().top + "px");
            } else {
                $pageSidebar.css("top", "0px");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Desisti do uso do scrollTop() pois estava apresentando um comportamento muito instável o que não é bom para aplicação.

Valeu a todos!

Comment: tente utilizando a propriedade nativa `window.scrollY`, além disso o correto é atribuir o evento `scroll` ao elemento `window`

Comment: @Sanção a propriedade `window.scrollY` também fica retornando `0`.

Comment: Veja se aqui te ajuda. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47462/fazer-else-em-jquery-para-controlar-scrolltop/47593#47593

Comment: Valeu galera. Com base nas sugestões e respostas cheguei a uma solução possível que coloquei no corpo da pergunta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Galera, após explorar um pouco mais e analisar as sugestões cheguei na seguinte solução.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var $body = $('body');
        var $pageSidebar = $('.page-sidebar');
        var $pageContainer = $('.page-container');

        $body.scroll(function (event) {

            if ($pageContainer.offset().top > 0) {
                $pageSidebar.css("top", $pageContainer.offset().top + "px");
            } else {
                $pageSidebar.css("top", "0px");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Desisti do uso do scrollTop() pois estava apresentando um comportamento muito instável o que não é bom para aplicação.